# How to access buttons in other class from Form1.cs

Tags: c#

I have 9 buttons in `Form1.Designer.cs` and I want to access them in another class, `Puzzle.cs` because later on I need to modify button changes in model class. The code below is what I attempted.

```
private Button[,] buttons = new Button[3, 3]
{ { Form1.button1, Form1.button2, Form1.button3 }, 
  { Form1.button4, Form1.button5, Form1.button6 }, 
  { Form1.button7, Form1.button8, Form1.button9 } };
```

It fails as the modifier for buttons is not static. I changed them into static type but this causes errors for buttons.
Can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference to an instance of the `Form1` class. If it were called `form`, you could then access the button like `form.button1`.

But I'm not sure accessing buttons of the form from another class is a good design.

Answer (score 0):

To get things compiling correctly, you'll need to make the following changes:

```
public partial class Puzzle : Form
{
    private Button[,] buttons;

    public Puzzle(Form1 form1)
    {
        buttons = new Button[,]
        {
            { form1.Button1, form1.Button2, form1.Button3, },
            { form1.Button4, form1.Button5, form1.Button6, },
            { form1.Button7, form1.Button8, form1.Button9, },
        }
    };
}
```

The idea here is that Form1 is a class, not an *instance* of a class... A class is like a blueprint of a house, and a house is like an *instance* of that blueprint.

To get furniture out of the house, you first must *instantiate and initialize* that house (build, if you will), and then access the house's furniture *instances*.

In this case, you'll need to *instantiate* a *new* Form1, and pass that to the Puzzle form's constructor.

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
Puzzle myPuzzle = new Puzzle(myForm);
```

Puzzle will now be able to access that instance of Form1's buttons.

**Note:**

You can find the Program's instance of Form1 by looking in the Program.cs file of your solution.

Comment: Thanks! But where do i put "Form1 myForm = new Form1();""Puzzle myPuzzle = new Puzzle(myForm);" these two lines???

Comment: As I stated, Program.cs Already has `Form1 myForm = new Form1();`, but the name of the Form1 reference variable may be something other than "myForm". Also, are you sure you need two forms? Perhaps "Puzzle" could just be a class, and not a Form.

Comment: Puzzle is a class. And why are those buttons still have null values when I'm trying to call them in Form1.cs. 'public void reset()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    buttons[i, j].BackColor = Color.Lime;
                }
        }' this is the method in Puzzle class. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You have to assign values to each button[x,y] index. `button[0,0] = form1.Button1`, etc, but `form1` must be an *instance* of a form, as stated above. To get the functionality you want you need to pass the instance variable `form1` to the constructor of Puzzle `var puzzle = new Puzzle(form1)`. Only then can you start using the buttons in your instance of Puzzle.