# NullReferenceException for button array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullreferenceexception

```
class Puzzle
      {
        private int PUZZLESIZE = 3;
        private int col, row;
        private Button[,] buttons;

        public Puzzle()
        { 
        }

        public Puzzle(Form1 form1)
        {
            buttons = new Button[3, 3] 
            { { form1.button1, form1.button2, form1.button3 }, 
            { form1.button4, form1.button5, form1.button6 }, 
            { form1.button7, form1.button8, form1.button9 } };          
        }

        public void reset()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    buttons[i, j].BackColor = Color.Lime;
                }
        }
```

**`buttons[i, j].BackColor = Color.Lime;`**

this line causes `NullReferenceException` when I call the reset method in Form1.cs. Any advice is appreciated!!!

Comment: Although the button properties are available on the form, it is possible that they haven't been instantiated yet, and thus would be null.  It depends on when you are trying to access them.  Standard WinForms behaviour is to create all controls in InitializeComponent, though this isn't set in stone.

Comment: Are you sure your code path doesn't use the default constructor, which doesn't bind the buttons?

Comment: I would start by removing the empty constructor...

Comment: Where you call `reset()` from? How are the buttons in `form1` built?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- It's possible that `form1.button1` (etc) are null. You should validate this in the constructor.
- If you call the parameterless constructor instead of the `Puzzle(Form1)` constructor, `buttons` will still be null. I suggest you get rid of the parameterless constructor.

I'd *also* advise that you use braces for *all* loops, i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        buttons[i, j].BackColor = Color.Lime;
    }
}
```

Yes, it takes more space - but it's clearer and less error-prone in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're calling the default constructor? It looks like your class requires a `Form1` instance to function, so try removing the default constructor. If it fails to build you've got your answer!

Comment: I think you are right. But how can I declare a puzzle instance with parameter in Form1.cs? Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle(...);

Comment: You'd write `Puzzle puzzle=new Puzzle(this);`

Comment: It says "keyword 'this' is not available in the current context" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883686/how-to-access-buttons-in-other-class-from-form1-cs Please also check this one. Thank you!!!

Comment: That's probably because you're initializing it where you declare the member variable. Do the initialization in the `Form1` constructor.